# How to change indices in a room migration?

Tags: android, migration, android-room

The old Entity as below:

```
@Entity(tableName = "d_course",
    foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = DUser.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "studio"),
    indices = @Index(value = "studio"))
```

The new Entity as below:

```
@Entity(tableName = "d_course",
    foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = DUser.class, parentColumns = "id", childColumns = "studio"),
    indices = @Index(value = {"id", "studio"}))
```

How do I migrate this **indices** change.

Comment: JUST FOR INFORMATION..... Here i would like to add some important things that ROOM expects.


Whenever you add a new column and write migration for it. do add this column at the end of other fields in MODEL class. (yessss! in model class) for ROOM order Matters.

and whenever you create an index. Always follow the convention i.e. <index_tableName_columnName> otherwise room will not letting u add the index.

Answer (score 11):

Try to specify this index changes in migration, for example (Kotlin):

```
val MIGRATION_1_2 = object : Migration(1, 2) {
    override fun migrate(database : SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
        ...
        database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX index_d_course_id_studio ON  d_course(id, studio)")
    }
}
```