# Migrate from greendao to Android Room

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, greendao

I have an existing Android application with greendao as ORM. However, for the future, I would prefer to use Android Room.

I rebuild now my database scheme in Android Room and I wanted to reuse an existing greendao managed SQLlite database. While doing queries in Android Room on this existing database, I receive the following error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle py_habits(...Habit).

Expected:
TableInfo{name='habits', columns={start_time_usual=Column{name='start_time_usual', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, end_place_id=Column{name='end_place_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, end_time_usual=Column{name='end_time_usual', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, start_place_id=Column{name='start_place_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, duration_usual=Column{name='duration_usual', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[Index{name='index_py_habits_id', unique=false, columns=[id]}]}
Found:
TableInfo{name='habits', columns={start_time_usual=Column{name='start_time_usual', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, end_place_id=Column{name='end_place_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, end_time_usual=Column{name='end_time_usual', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, id=Column{name='id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1}, start_place_id=Column{name='start_place_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}, duration_usual=Column{name='duration_usual', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[Index{name='IDX_py_habits_id', unique=false, columns=[id]}]}
```

Actually, I can see just two differences - the order of the columns is different (start_place_id and id are changed in order) and greendao gave the index a different prefix (IDX vs. index).

Is there a way to migrate the schema so I can use Android Room instead of greendao?

Comment: i have never done this but afaik the column are made in order of their declaration in your @Entity class. So maybe switching the declaration may do the job for you.

Comment: about the second issue : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49252466/1042124

Comment: Thanks, I will try the sample code concerning index you proposed... but to your second point: in the entity the order is actually id -> start_place_id... in greendao and Android Room. I hope it is just a problem with the index...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Rahul Kumar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1042124/rahul-kumar) for his hint in the comments of my question.

Actually, it was just a problem with the name of the indices. I had to rename all table indices from the prefix IDX_ to index_ in my migration.

Here is the example for just one of my tables (I did it of course for all with indices):

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_2_3 = new Migration(2, 3) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Rename indices because of switch from Greendao to Android Room
        database.execSQL("DROP INDEX IDX_habits_id");
        database.execSQL("CREATE INDEX index_habits_id ON habits(id)");
    }
};
```